# How do you introspect MooseX::Method::Signatures methods to see what arguements they take?

Tags: perl, moose, method-signature

I'm using MooseX::Declare and methods, which uses MooseX::Method::Signatures. Let's say I have a class 'foo' with a method 'bar', and I've implemented it like:

```
class foo {
    method bar (Str $str, Bool :$flag = 1) {
        # ....
    }
}
```

I now want to write a front-end interface that asks a user what class they want to use, what method on that class they want to use, and then what options to the method they want. I can do the first two things, so let's say the user has now chosen class foo and method bar.

But how do I find out that method bar takes a string as the first argument, and a flag => bool key value pair that defaults to 1? My code needs to know this so I can then ask the user to supply these things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, get the method meta object:

```
my $method = $class->meta->find_method_by_name( $method_name );
```

Then, make sure it's a signaturey method:

```
confess "not method with a signature!"
  unless $method->isa('MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method');
```

Get its signature:

```
my $sig = $method->parsed_signature;
```

Then look at `$sig`'s `named_params` and `positional_params` as detailed in [the Parse::Method::Signatures::Sig docs](http://p3rl.org/Parse%3a%3aMethod%3a%3aSignatures%3a%3aSig).

To find `parsed_signature`, I had to look at the [source to MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/MooseX-Method-Signatures/MooseX/Method/Signatures/Meta/Method.pm.html)… so be wary when you do this.